# Can I work remotely in US with a F2 Visa?

Tags: visas, usa

My Fiancé has been admitted for PhD in the US. I am a Tech Support Engineer with 2.5 years of experience. Can I work remotely from the US for a different country?, if not, is there any other ways to find legal employment in the US?(I am trying to get a H1B,but not sure if I will get it for my experience)

Comment: This is more relevant at our sister site https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

As F-2, you cannot work at all. If your spouse gets J-1 status instead of F-1, then you could apply for [work permission as J-2](https://j1visa.state.gov/basics/j2-visa/). Getting J-1 instead of F-1 depends on the program and university, and is often an option for PhD programs at large universities.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I work remotely in US with a F2 Visa?

No. The same question was asked on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/572/living-in-the-us-on-an-f2-visa-and-working-remotely-for-a-canadian-company, where you'll find other options.